# Setting dropdown list selected value in Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I have a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2010 and I was wondering how I would set a default selected value of a dropdown menu.

For example, when I run the project currently the dropdown menu is blank until I click on it and select a value. I want to modify the dropdown menu so that it has a value by default that the user can then change. How can I accomplish this both in the designer view and at runtime through C#?

Comment: Which UI framework are you using (Winforms, WPF, etc.)? Or since you seem to think your question pertains directly to Visual Studio, is there a particular Visual Studio drop down you want defaulted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set property SelectedIndex.

**Run-time:**

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //Selects the first option
```

If you want to select option that contains specific text.

```
int index = comboBox1.FindString("burger"); //get index
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
```

**Design-time:**

Select the control, go to property window and look for SelectedIndex property, set the desired index.